# How to find values in multidimensional array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, find

I'd like to know to to find a number that's been typed in by the user so that number will be printed. the idea is to read from left to right and from top to bottom and from bottom to top. Here is my code so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace opgave1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            int R = 8;
            int K = 10;
            int[,] matrix = new int[R, K];

            PrintMatrix(matrix, R, K);



            Console.Write("give a number: ");
            int nummer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
//TODO TDO TODOOD 


            Console.ReadKey();


        }


        private static void PrintMatrix(int[,] matrix, int R, int K)
        {

            Random random = new Random();
            for (int h = 0; h < R; h++)
            {

                for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
                {
                    matrix[h, k] = random.Next(1, 101);
                    Console.Write("{0,3}", matrix[h, k]);

                }
                Console.WriteLine();


            }
        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the main program replace Console.ReadKey() by :

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

One way to solve it is via brute force. Go through whole matrix in nested loops, and find the element one by one. In C#, you don't need to pass length and width of the array, hence skipping R and K, you used in your `PrintMatrix()` function and calculated it from input matrix itself.

```
        private static void Print(int[,] matrix, int num)
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        int R = matrix.GetLength(0);
        int K = matrix.GetLength(1);
        for (int h = 0; h < R; h++)
        {

            for (int k = 0; k < K; k++)
            {
                if(matrix[h, k] == num)
                     Console.Write("{0,1}", h,k);

            }
            Console.WriteLine();


        }
    }
```

Another way is to use hashmap, where you can preprocess the created matrix and save matrix element as key, and indices as value.